# Using a distance sensor in Processing to control the attributes of shapes

Tags: arduino, processing, arduino-uno

I'm trying to make a program that will use the readings it gets from a distance sensor to control the attributes of circles (size, xy and colour). To do this I'm trying to make it record the current value and apply that to the value when you press the relevant key (Eg. press 's' and it changes the size to whatever the distance was at that point). - Ideally I'd like the circle to change whatever field is next dynamically as you move your hand over the sensor, but that seems a bit beyond me.

I've tried to do as much as I can, but everything I'm not sure of I've commented out. Any tips or advice? I'm really not sure what I'm doing when it comes to classes and constructors.

EDIT: When I run the code, nothing happens.

```
import processing.serial.*;

int xpos, ypos, s, r, g, b;

Circle circle;
int shapeSize, distance;
String comPortString;
Serial myPort;


void setup(){
 size(displayWidth,displayHeight); //Use entire screen size.

//Open the serial port for communication with the Arduino
myPort = new Serial(this, "/dev/cu.usbmodem1411", 9600);
myPort.bufferUntil('\n'); // Trigger a SerialEvent on new line
}

void draw(){
 background(0);
 delay(50); //Delay used to refresh screen

println(distance);
}


void serialEvent(Serial cPort){
comPortString = (new String(cPort.readBytesUntil('\n')));
 if(comPortString != null) {
 comPortString=trim(comPortString);

 /* Use the distance received by the Arduino to modify the y position
 of the first square (others will follow). Should match the
 code settings on the Arduino. In this case 200 is the maximum
 distance expected. The distance is then mapped to a value
 between 1 and the height of your screen */
 distance = int(map(Integer.parseInt(comPortString),1,200,1,height));
 if(distance<0){
 /*If computer receives a negative number (-1), then the
 sensor is reporting an "out of range" error. Convert all
 of these to a distance of 0. */
 distance = 0;
 }
 }
}



void keyPressed()
{
  // N for new circle (and keep old one)
  if((key == 'N') || (key == 'n')) {
    println("n");
  circle = new Circle(1,1,1,1,1,1);
    }

    //r - change red
      if((key == 'R') || (key == 'r')) {
    float red = map(distance, 0, 700, 0, 255);

    r = int(red);
    println("r " + r);
    }

       //g - change green
      if((key == 'G') || (key == 'g')) {
    float green = map(distance, 0, 700, 0, 255);
   g = int(green);
     println("g " + g);
    }

          //b - change blue
      if((key == 'B') || (key == 'b')) {
    float blue = map(distance, 0, 700, 0, 255);
     b = int(blue);
     println("b " + b);

    }

    //S - change Size
      if((key == 'S') || (key == 's')) {
       s = distance;
        println("s " + s);
    }

    //X - change x  pos
      if((key == 'X') || (key == 'x')) {
     xpos = distance;
         println("x " + xpos);
    }

    //y - change y pos
      if((key == 'Y') || (key == 'y')) {
            ypos = distance;
      println("y " + ypos);
    }
  } 

  class Circle {

   Circle(int xpos, int ypos, int s, int r, int g, int b){
   ellipse(xpos, ypos, s, s);
   color(r, g, b);
   }
   int getX(){
     return xpos;
   }
      int getY(){
     return ypos;
   }
  }
```

Comment: On the first line of the serialEvent function you could simply use the [readString()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_readString_.html) function: ```comPortString = cPort.readString();```, other than that code looks like it should work. Are you getting any data from Arduino ? A bit off topic: what distance sensor are you using ? ( I remember using some Sharp IR ones a while back and had use a formula to map the raw analog value to a distance)

Comment: its a HC-SR04. Yeah I just kind of guessed the mapping

Comment: Ok. So is the working now ? If not, what isn't working / how is it behaving ?

Comment: I've posted a new question here with updated code and a better worded question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116313/creating-a-circle-drawing-program-in-processing-with-distance-sensor

But yes, the distance sensor is functioning fine, I'm just getting flashing rogue circles everywhere.

Comment: The code in the new post looks a bit messier than the code you posted here. There are a couple of things that stand out:1. You only update your circle on key events. Perhaps you should update values continuously as they come from Serial, but switch which circle property is currently used based on keys  1. You're creating a new Circle object/int every single frame (perhaps you can reuse the same object and simply update it's properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split this into steps/tasks:

1. Connecting to the Arduino
2. Reading values from Arduino
3. Mapping read values
4. Controlling mapping

You've got the Arduino part pretty much there, but things look messy when trying to map read values to the circle on screen. 
For now, for simplicity reasons, let's ignore classes and focus on simply drawing a single ellipse with x,y,size,r,g,b properties.

To get read of jitter you should update the property ellipse continuously, not just when pressing a key. On the key event you should simply change what property gets updated.
You could use extra variables to keep track of what ellipse properties you're updating.

Here's a refactored version of the code based on the points above:

```
import processing.serial.*;

int xpos,ypos,s,r,g,b;
int distance;

int propertyID = 0;//keep track of what property should be updated on distance
int PROP_XPOS = 0;
int PROP_YPOS = 1;
int PROP_S = 2;
int PROP_R = 3;
int PROP_G = 4;
int PROP_B = 5;

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  //setup some defaults to see something on screen
  xpos = ypos = 200;
  s = 20;
  r = g = b = 127;
  //initialize arduino - search for port based on OSX name
  String[] portNames = Serial.list();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < portNames.length; i++){
    if(portNames[i].contains("usbmodem")){
      try{
        Serial arduino = new Serial(this,portNames[i],9600);
        arduino.bufferUntil('\n');
        return;
      }catch(Exception e){
        showSerialError();
      }
    }
  }
  showSerialError();
}
void showSerialError(){
  System.err.println("Error connecting to Arduino!\nPlease check the USB port");
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  fill(r,g,b);
  ellipse(xpos,ypos,s,s);
}
void serialEvent(Serial arduino){
  String rawString = arduino.readString();//fetch raw string
  if(rawString != null){
    String trimmedString = rawString.trim();//trim the raw string
    int rawDistance = int(trimmedString);//convert to integer
    distance = (int)map(rawDistance,1,200,1,height);
    updatePropsOnDistance();//continously update circle properties
  }
}
void updatePropsOnDistance(){
  if(propertyID == PROP_XPOS) xpos = distance;
  if(propertyID == PROP_YPOS) ypos = distance;
  if(propertyID == PROP_S) s = distance;
  if(propertyID == PROP_R) r = distance;
  if(propertyID == PROP_G) g = distance;
  if(propertyID == PROP_B) b = distance;
}
void keyReleased(){//only change what proprty changes on key press
  if(key == 'x' || key == 'X') propertyID = PROP_XPOS;
  if(key == 'y' || key == 'Y') propertyID = PROP_YPOS;
  if(key == 's' || key == 'S') propertyID = PROP_S;
  if(key == 'r' || key == 'R') propertyID = PROP_R;
  if(key == 'g' || key == 'G') propertyID = PROP_G;
  if(key == 'b' || key == 'B') propertyID = PROP_B;
}
//usually a good idea to test - in this case use mouseY instead of distance sensor
void mouseDragged(){
  distance = mouseY;
  updatePropsOnDistance();
}
```

If this makes sense, it can easily be encapsulated in a class.
We could use an array to store those properties, but if something like props[0] for x, props[1](https://processing.org/reference/IntDict.html) for y, etc. is harder to read, you could use an [IntDict](https://processing.org/reference/IntDict.html) which allows you to index values based on a String instead of a value (so you can do `props["x"]` instead of `props[0]`).

Here's an encapsulated version of the code:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Circle circle = new Circle();

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  //initialize arduino - search for port based on OSX name
  String[] portNames = Serial.list();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < portNames.length; i++){
    if(portNames[i].contains("usbmodem")){
      try{
        Serial arduino = new Serial(this,portNames[i],9600);
        arduino.bufferUntil('\n');
        return;
      }catch(Exception e){
        showSerialError();
      }
    }
  }
  showSerialError();
}
void showSerialError(){
  System.err.println("Error connecting to Arduino!\nPlease check the USB port");
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  circle.draw();
}
void serialEvent(Serial arduino){
  String rawString = arduino.readString();
  if(rawString != null){
    String trimmedString = rawString.trim();
    int rawDistance = int(trimmedString);
    int distance = (int)map(rawDistance,1,200,1,height);
    circle.update(distance);
  }
}
void keyReleased(){
  circle.setUpdateProperty(key+"");//update the circle property based on what key gets pressed. the +"" is a quick way to make a String from the char
}
//usually a good idea to test - in this case use mouseY instead of distance sensor
void mouseDragged(){
  circle.update(mouseY);
}

class Circle{
  //an IntDict (integer dictionary) is an associative array where instead of accessing values by an integer index (e.g. array[0]
  //you access them by a String index (e.g. array["name"])
  IntDict properties = new IntDict();

  String updateProperty = "x";//property to update

  Circle(){
    //defaults
    properties.set("x",200);
    properties.set("y",200);
    properties.set("s",20);
    properties.set("r",127);
    properties.set("g",127);
    properties.set("b",127);
  }

  void draw(){
    fill(properties.get("r"),properties.get("g"),properties.get("b"));
    ellipse(properties.get("x"),properties.get("y"),properties.get("s"),properties.get("s"));
  }

  void setUpdateProperty(String prop){
    if(properties.hasKey(prop)) updateProperty = prop;
    else{
      println("circle does not contain property: " + prop+"\navailable properties:");
      println(properties.keyArray());
    } 
  }

  void update(int value){
    properties.set(updateProperty,value);   
  }

}
```

In both examples you can test the distance value by dragging your mouse on the Y axis.

Regarding the HC-SR04 sensor, you can find [code on the Arduino Playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/NewPing) to get the distance in cm. I haven't used the sensor myself yet, but I notice other people has some issues with it, so it's worth checking [this post](http://therandomlab.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/repair-and-solve-faulty-hc-sr04.html) as well. If you want to roll your own Arduino code, no problem, you can use the [HC-SR04 datasheet](http://www.micropik.com/PDF/HCSR04.pdf)(pdf link) to get the formula:

> Formula: uS / 58 = centimeters or uS / 148 =inch; or: the range = high
>   level time * velocity (340M/S) / 2; we suggest to use over 60ms
>   measurement cycle, in order to prevent trigger signal to the echo
>   signal.

It's important to get accurate values (you'll avoid jitter when using these to draw in Processing). Additionally you can use [easing](https://processing.org/examples/easing.html) or a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Simple_moving_average).

Here's a basic moving average example:

```
int historySize = 25;//remember a number of past values
int[] x = new int[historySize];
int[] y = new int[historySize];

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  background(255);
  noFill();
}
void draw(){
  //draw original trails in red
  stroke(192,0,0,127);
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,10,10);

  //compute moving average 
  float avgX = average(x,mouseX);
  float avgY = average(y,mouseY);

  //draw moving average in green
  stroke(0,192,0,127);
  ellipse(avgX,avgY,10,10); 
}
void mouseReleased(){
  background(255);
}
float average(int[] values,int newValue){
  //shift elements by 1, from the last to the 2nd: count backwards
  float total = 0;
  int size = values.length;
  for(int i = size-1; i > 0; i--){//count backwards
    values[i] = values[i-1];//copy previous value into current
    total += values[i];//add values to total
  }
  values[0] = newValue;//add the newest value at the start of the list
  total += values[0];//add the latest value to the total
  return (float)total/size;//return the average
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful! :)